# C# lambda and ascending values in array

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an array of numbers and I want to find the first series (with a count more than one) of contiguous ascending numbers within it.

Example input: `{5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 6, 9}`
Desired output:  `{1, 2, 4, 8}`

Comment: You mean to return only the _longest_ ascending sequence?

Comment: Are you going to find the longest increasing subsequence? or just any?

Comment: No, only the first one, or even better - the first one starting a given index :)

Comment: I doubt it can be done with a lambda, but we might as well get some more detail. Do you only want to return the first such sequence? In your example, `{6, 9}` is also a series of ascending numbers in your input. Or do you want to find the longest sequence of ascending numbers?

Comment: @DanielA.White: I tried using the "Where" and "FindAll" methods of Array, but I don't know how to refer to the items indices.

Comment: @Idov If you want the first, then wouldn't it be `5, 8, 9`?  Why do you skip 5 and start with 1?

Comment: @servy: The ascending series has to be continuous.

Comment: Well, the first ascending series for that input would then be `5`.  (Unless, as asked, you want the longest, or the first sequence with a count more than one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should find the first ascending sequence from a given starting index:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetAscending(IEnumerable<int> input, int startIndex)
{
    var ascending = input.Skip(startIndex)
        .Zip(input.Skip(startIndex + 1), (first, second) => new { Num = first, Next = second, Diff = second - first })
        .SkipWhile(p => p.Diff <= 0)
        .TakeWhile(p => p.Diff > 0)
        .Select(p => Tuple.Create(p.Num, p.Next))
        .ToArray();

    if(ascending.Length == 0) return Enumerable.Empty<int>();

    return ascending.Select(t => t.Item1).Concat(new int[] { ascending.Last().Item2 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<int> getAscendingValues(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    List<int> output = new List<int>();

    foreach (int next in source)
    {
        if (output.Count == 0 || output.Last() < next)
        {
            output.Add(next);
        }
        else
        {
            if (output.Count <= 1)
            {
                output.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                return output;
            }
        }
    }

    if (output.Count > 1)
    {
        return output;
    }
    else
    {
        return null; //could also return an empty enumeration
    }
}
```

If you want to start at a specific index you can just use the `Skip` method before calling this, rather than adding an extra parameter to support it.  (i.e. `getAscendingValues(values.Skip(startIndex))`)